# How to include a local executable when building an Electron app with Electron-builder

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

My project requires a small executable tool to be local to the project directory. However, when I build my project with electron builder, the executable isn't included in the distribution.

The executable is run by spawning a child_process.exec using Node.js. Of course, this requires a file location.

How do I ensure this file gets packaged with my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use [extraResources](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#extraresources)

```
 ..........
```